# haproxy + Apache + virtual hosts -> wrong host is displayed

Tags: dns, apache, apache2, vhost, haproxy

On CentOS 7.2.1511 Linux I have installed
haproxy-1.5.14-3.el7.x86_64 and
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64 packages.

The `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` binds HAProxy to
ports 80 and 443 and accepts HTTPS to slova.de:

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
....
frontend public
    bind 144.76.184.151:80
    bind 144.76.184.151:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/slova.de.pem
    reqidel ^X-Forwarded-Proto:
    reqidel ^X-Forwarded-For:
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    default_backend apache

backend apache
    server domain 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` binds Apache
to port 8080 and serves few Wordpress sites:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
ServerName 144.76.184.151

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/afarber.de
    ServerName afarber.de
    ErrorLog logs/afarber.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/afarber.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ruhrgebietsingle.de
    ServerName ruhrgebietsingle.de
    ErrorLog logs/ruhrgebietsingle.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/ruhrgebietsingle.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bukvy.de
    ServerName bukvy.de
    ErrorLog logs/bukvy.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/bukvy.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/slova.de
    ServerName slova.de
    ErrorLog logs/slova.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/slova.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open http://slova.de or https://slova.de they work fine.

But when I try to open the above URLs
with `www.` prepended, the browser displays
http://ruhrgebietsingle.de (the 2nd site out of 4) instead.

Why does it happen? I just can not figure it out.

What tool would help here to debug?

In debug console of Chrome browser I see `301 Moved Permanently` - but who and why sends it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had to add `ServerAlias` for each server, didn't think of it because before I had a mod_rewrite rule to remove the `www.` prefix...

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/afarber.de
    ServerName afarber.de
    ServerAlias *.afarber.de
    ErrorLog logs/afarber.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/afarber.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ruhrgebietsingle.de
    ServerName ruhrgebietsingle.de
    ServerAlias *.ruhrgebietsingle.de
    ErrorLog logs/ruhrgebietsingle.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/ruhrgebietsingle.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bukvy.de
    ServerName bukvy.de
    ServerAlias *.bukvy.de
    ErrorLog logs/bukvy.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/bukvy.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/slova.de
    ServerName slova.de
    ServerAlias *.slova.de
    ErrorLog logs/slova.de/error_log
    CustomLog logs/slova.de/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am glad you found your answer. That was the first thing I thought of. Cheers!!